# How to transfer specific parts of text/information from one cell to multiple respective cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help taking specific parts of text from one cell and transferring it into several other cells. Under the 'Pole Info' category, the amount/typ of characters for each category (Pole type, drawing code, and is blemish/scrap/blank) change every time.

In the Pole Info column for example: V49084RAU 17.5 54323 49F 214 2273 BlEMISH

The first 5 Numbers (49084) in the 1st block of text are the pole type entered as 490/84

The next block of info (17.5) is the Flex Number. Sometimes the flex number can appear in the 1st block of text as well.

The 3rd or 4th block of info (49F) is the Drawing code. This can sometimes be longer than 3 characters or even be all letters.

The next block of info (2273) is the weight. Sometimes this can be 3 numbers.

Finally, the last block on info can contain BLEMISH, SCRAP, or be blank. This needs to go in the respective columns (Is Scrap, Is blemish, or both columns need to either say "No" or left blank)

There are several variations of the Pole Info so I will provide examples. Row 3 is an example of how a correct row looks:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErFzt.png)

I tried to use formulas in each individual cells but had a difficult time making it robust as the pole info information varies in format. I am not sure if it would be better to do it in VBA, but I am confused as on how to start since I am inexpereinced in VBA.

I have used `=IFERROR(LEFT(B2, FIND(" ", B2)-1), G2)` for the pole type so far but cant figure out what to do for the rest.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.)

Comment: So use mid() and use find() to find the spaces as they seem to be the delimiter in the example you show. To find the second space use find() inside find(). Lots of fum trying these :)

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes
    Dim objRegExp As Object, objMatch As Object
    Const COL_CNT = 7
    ' Create RegExp object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z]+(\d{3})(\d\d)[a-z]+\s*([\d\.]+)\s+\d+\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)(?:\s+([a-z]+))*"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    ' Load data
    Set rngData = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To COL_CNT)
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        Set objMatch = objRegExp.Execute(arrData(i, 1))
        ' Load ouput
        If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
            With objMatch(0)
                arrRes(i, 1) = .submatches(0) & "/" & .submatches(1)
                arrRes(i, 2) = "'" & .submatches(3)
                arrRes(i, 3) = "'" & .submatches(2)
                arrRes(i, 4) = "'" & .submatches(4)
                arrRes(i, 5) = "'" & .submatches(5)
                If .submatches.Count > 5 Then
                    If StrComp(.submatches(6), "SCRAP", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        arrRes(i, 6) = "SCRAP"
                    ElseIf StrComp(.submatches(6), "BLEMISH", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        arrRes(i, 7) = "BLEMISH"
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrData), COL_CNT).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144121)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: thanks for the insight on how to solve this problem. appreciate it